# Azure App Service Kudu tool "LogFiles" Deleted Automatically -- app service for container (linux)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I hosted my dotnet core app on app service for containers and I'm using the standard logging to log http request, but when I check my log files from kudu, it seems that files deleted automatically each day to add new day-file

As example,

on 25/10/2020 I got those files
(22-10-2020_docker_log, 19-10-2020_docker_log, 25-10-2020_docker_log)

and on 26/10/2020 I got those files
(22-10-2020_docker_log, 19-10-2020_docker_log, 26-10-2020_docker_log)

Why this happened? is log files deleted daily? I think it should never deleted, isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Enable application logging by navigating to your app, select App Service logs.

In Application logging, select File System.

In Quota (MB), specify the disk quota for the application logs. In Retention Period (Days), set the number of days the logs should be retained.

Click Save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already enabled log to file system and quota to 35 MB, and retention period with 7 days.
But when I donwnload the log files as zip from kudu it contain only the above files only and the size of zip file is 170 KB!